# How to replace specific characters using regsub?

Tags: regex, tcl

I am using tcl 8.5.

I want to cut every line not ending with `,` or `"` in my input.

**input**

```
karthik*
software engineer,
```

I tried ,

```
regsub -all {[^",]\n} $content {} content
```

**expected output**

```
karthik*software engineer,
```

**output**

```
karthiksoftware engineer,
```

The character `*` is missing .I understand `[^,"]` in regsub matches * and it is cut.
But how can i cut only `\n` and not `*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're throwing out the char before the newline along with the newline.

```
regsub -all {([^",])\n} $content {\1} content 
# ...........^.....^..............^^
```

Comment: Could you please explain the role of `\1` in regsub ?

Comment: @Karthik `\1` refers to what the first (capturing) parenthesis was around.